# Dynamic sql query from MS SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, openquery, odbc-sql-server-driver

I have 2 dbs one on MS SQL and another on Mysql. I have written some sql scriots which fetch data from Mysql and insert into MS SQL. To do this I have set up device driver connection and linked server on MS SQL and these scripts are executed on MS SQL. Scripts are simple and have only select statements. 
Now I need to write dynamic scripts to fetch data from mysql based on some parameters. Below is sample query to get data from DB "stagedb_ie" where ie stands for Ireland.

`select * from openquery(stagedb_ie, 'select * from stagedb_ie.aol_center')`

There are other dbs in mysql with country code suffix to stagedb as name. Now I want to pass this country code as parameter to query and get data. e.g.

```
declare @stagedb_country varchar(20)
set @stagedb_country = 'stagedb_ie'
select * from openquery(@stagedb_country, 'select * from '+ @stagedb_country +'.aol_center')
```

But this query doesn't work. any suggestion?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '@stagedb_country'.

Comment: Where is the error shown? you have the variable in three places.

Comment: in select query near openquery(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @stagedb_country varchar(20),
   @SQL nvarchar(max);
set @stagedb_country = 'stagedb_ie';
set @SQL = 'select * from openquery(' + @stagedb_country
   + ', ''select * from ' + @stagedb_country + '.aol_center'')';
exec (@SQL);
```

Be aware that dynamic SQL in SPs executes with the permissions of the caller not the SP owner.

Last, I question why you're using separate databases and tables for this. Can you not encode what you need in the data instead of putting the data in different containers?

Comment: Actually I'm not owner of mysql dbs, these dbs and tables have been there already.